# Whats the minimum angle needed for the player to avoid the obstacle

Tags: math, geometry, 2d

I need a method that in a 2D space, you are given the player's position, radius & direction and are also given the position and radius of the obstacle, what is the minimum angle that the player's direction needs to be rotated to avoid the obstacle.

[image]

Comment: If you are struggling to implement this, please show what you have tried so far, and point out the specific problem you are having. If you haven't tried to solve it yourself yet, you should do that.

Comment: Hint: Create a line that is perpendicular to the line OP. Project the shape on that line.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to figure out the calculation needed for this. Once I know the calculation needed, then implementing will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I see it like this:

[image: overview]

so you are finding direction from player (brown line) that is tangent to obstacle with radius increased by player radius.

Lets define some stuff first:

```cpp
p0=(x0,y0) // player position
dp=(dx,dy) // player direction 
p1=(x1,y1) // obstacle position
r0         // player radius
r1         // obstacle radius
t =(tx,ty) // intersection of new direction and (r0+r1) obstacle circle
```

then:

```cpp
dot( t-p0 , t-p1 ) = 0 // perpendicular vectors
|t-p1| = r0+r1         // the intersection is at r0+r1 distance from obstacle center
dt=t-p0                // new direction
```

these lead to system of quadratic equations:

```cpp
(tx-x0)*(tx-x1) + (ty-y0)*(ty-y1) = 0
(tx-x1)*(tx-x1) + (ty-y1)*(ty-y1) = (r0+r1)*(r0+r1)
```

so solve it and chose the solution that is closer to `p0` or has bigger result of:

```cpp
dot( t-p0 , dp )
```

which gives you also the `cos` of your angle change without sign. Now the signed angle change is done like this:

```cpp
ang = atan2(ty-y0,tx-x0) - atan2(dy,dx)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Find the Inner tangents.

   *direction D is RAY when both tangents are LINES or LINE SEGMENTS.*
2. so D have 2 angles with single tangent1, as like x & (180-x)
   take the minimum one, as t1
3. find t2 as second step.

   *you have 2 minimum angle with both tangents, as t1 & t2*
4. **minimum of t1 & t2** that's the player's direction needs to be rotated to avoid the obstacle.